# Python3 replace using dictionary

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, replace

Could anyone please explain what is wrong here:

```
def get_complementary_sequence(string):
    dic = {'A':'T', 'C':'G', 'T':'A', 'G':'C'}
    for a, b in dic.items():
        string = string.replace(a, b)
    return string
```

I get proper results for 'T' and 'C', but 'A' and 'C' won't replace. Got really stuck.

String looks like 'ACGTACG'.

Comment: You're iterating over each item of the dictionary in order, so they are all being replaced correctly!  The problem is that when you replace T, A has already been replaced by T, so you replace it back.

Comment: now that you are trying to deal with DNA sequence, I suggest you to use [BioPython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page) instead

Answer (score 6):

You are first replacing all `A`s with `T`s before then replacing all `T`s with `A`s again (including those you just replaced `A`s with!):

```
>>> string = 'ACGTACG'
>>> string.replace('A', 'T')
'TCGTTCG'
>>> string.replace('A', 'T').replace('T', 'A')
'ACGAACG'
```

Use a translation map instead, fed to [`str.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
transmap = {ord('A'): 'T', ord('C'): 'G', ord('T'): 'A', ord('G'): 'C'}
return string.translate(transmap)
```

The `str.translate()` method requires a dictionary mapping codepoints (integers) to replacement characters (either a single character or a codepoint), or `None` (to delete the codepoint from the input string). The `ord()` function gives us those codepoints for the given 'from' letters.

This looks up characters in `string`, one by one in C code, in the translation map, instead of replacing all `A`s followed by all `T`s.

`str.translate()` has the added advantage of being *much* faster than a series of `str.replace()` calls.

Demo:

```
>>> string = 'ACGTACG'
>>> transmap = {ord('A'): 'T', ord('C'): 'G', ord('T'): 'A', ord('G'): 'C'}
>>> string.translate(transmap)
'TGCATGC'
```

Comment: `str.translate()` is also much faster than the naive `''.join(dic[c] for c in s)`.

Answer (score 2):

Mutable data is your enemy :)

See, you first replace all `A`s with `T`s, *then*, in another iteration, replace all `T`s with `A`s again.

What works:

```
# for Creek and Watson's sake, name your variables sensibly
complements = {ord('A'):'T', ord('C'):'G', ord('T'):'A', ord('G'):'C'}
sequence = "AGCTTCAG"
print(sequence.translate(complements))
```

It prints `TCGAAGTC`.